# How to hard-reset shiny server by R command

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use Shiny as a stand-alone application, like this.

```
R --quiet --no-save -e "shiny::runApp('ui', 8080)" &
firefox -new-window "http://localhost:8080" &
```

It is good, but sometimes I need to reset a background for several reasons such as 1) reload markup files using `includeMarkdown` and/or 2) reload data files. However, I failed to google it therefore I'd appreciate if someone let me know how to do this.

Comment: You could write a shell script that kills the currently running shiny server if there is one, and starts a new one. Then in shiny you could just use the `system()` command to call that script.  Sounds weird, but it should work... hopefully someone has a better solution